# Teechart + logarithm Scale

Tags: activex, teechart

If I change the Left Axis Scale to Log 10. It should start with 1 instead of Zero. If I do it manually also say I say Min as 1, Max as 1000 and Incr =100 then it doesn't show me the starting point (i.e 1). It shows all the points except that.

Max Position on Y axis is Not shown

[image]

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below works fine for me with TeeChart Pro ActiveX 2013

```
TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

TChart1.AddSeries scLine

TChart1.Axis.Left.Logarithmic = True
TChart1.Axis.Left.LogarithmicBase = 10


For i = 0 To 1000
    TChart1.Series(0).Add i, "", clTeeColor
Next
```

Does it work fine for you? Which TeeChart version are you using?

Comment: TeeChart201264 actually  I am setting Y axis Automatic to False and trying it, It get reflected in the Y - Axis Min Value but not in Y -axis Items

Comment: @AkshayBhalla I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Does the code I posted work fine for you?

Comment: Your Code Works fine the sample code I have but not in my actual code :-(

Comment: Actually the problem was I was setting Increment to a value for log it should be set to zero